# Existe a possibilidade de montar no Bootstrap um CSS especifico para um tamanho

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de criar um css que quando uma certa classe estivesse em no tamanho xs teria um font-color red e os demais tamanhos esta cor mudaria para green. 
Porém sem ter que repetir o texto. tipo:

```html
<div class="hidden-xs">
   <div class="Vermelho">
       Teste
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl">
   <div class="verde">
       Teste
   </div>
</div>
```

Queria uma classe teria duas alternativa de cor dependendo do tamanho...

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="Cor">
       Teste
   </div>
</div>
```

Será que é possivel tal façanha? POde ser em CSS ou JS.
Agradeço desde de já pela ajuda

Comment: importe um ficheiro css, com a seguinte configuração .col-xs-12 {color:red;} .col-sm-12 {color:blue;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O CSS 3 permite que você crie seletores usando *substrings* dos valores de atributos. Por exemplo, se você quiser estilizar links que contém `http://` no atributo `href`, sem ir direto na tag `<a>`, você poderia fazer isso:

```css
[href*="http://"]{
  color: red;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com">Stack overflow</a>
```

Veja que em nenhum momento atribui nada a tag `<a>`. Para montar um seletor que atribua regras a tudo que tem a substring `-xs` nas classes, você pode fazer

```
[class*="-xs"]{
  color: red;
}
```

Mas isso não é lá muito performático, pois faz comparações com todos os nomes de classe. Não é uma prática muito boa.

[Leia mais sobre isso aqui](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: Muito bom! Não sabia disso! Eu usei o LESS e funcionou

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, aceite-a como a correta! =)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma solução alternativa usando o LESS como abaixo:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 footer div {
      color: rgb(xx, xx, xx);
 }
}
```